# How do I check a typed pointer is properly aligned for that type?

Tags: c++, alignment

Suppose I have a templated function that deals with pointers to yet unknown type `T`. Now if type `T` happens to be `void*` on 64-bit platform then it must be 8-bytes aligned, but if `T` happens to be `char` it must be 1-byte aligned and if `T` happens to be a class then its alignment requirements will depend on its member variables.

This all can be computed on paper, but how do I make the compiler yield the alignment requirements for a given type `T`?

Is there a way to find during compile time the alignment requirements for a given type?

Comment: compiler automatically do that! what are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: There's the `alignof` keyword in C++11.

Comment: @BigBoss: I'm using a custom allocator and I want to be sure that it returns properly aligned pointers at all times.

Comment: OK, then you may use `alignof` of C++11 or you may align to sizeof `double` this is not standard but it work for all kind of compilers that I know!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++11 you can use [alignof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignof) and [alignas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas) to make asserts and provide requirements for alignment. Also look at [std::align](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align) to control alignment in runtime.

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of C++11, its easiest to use the next power-of-two greater than or equal to `sizeof(T)`. You might also want to cap it to the alignment of the largest primitive. 8 is a pretty safe bet on a 64-bit architecture (though you might need to keep an eye on things like SSE data types).